# The Walking Dead: Wifi & Pilots?

Tags: the-walking-dead

How come in gated communities like Alexandria where there's electricity and normal appliances there is no computer with a wifi connection? Telecomm companies might have been zombie infested but that doesn't explain how or why no one has an internet connection. Furthermore, airports might have stopped operating but it's not like the landing strips aren't there. It's as if they are suggesting all pilots and private jet owners have died or zombified. All those semi-peaceful days in Alexandria  you'd think they'd try to get in contact with similar communities around the world and bring civilization and peace back.

Comment: Internet has to be maintained by real people, and I imagine they had other priorities at the time. _Someone has to protect Wikipedia form bot edits_

Comment: _" Telecomm companies might have been zombie infested but that doesn't explain how or why no one has an internet connection"_ Pretty sure it does.

Comment: Regarding aircraft, IIRC there WAS a helicopter seen flying around a couple times in the earlier seasons.  I don't recall them ever figuring out who that was.  Also consider that airplanes are LOUD, and zombies are attracted to noise.  It would be difficult to maintain an active airstrip because frequent take off/landing noises would draw zombies from miles around.

Comment: power plants need maintenance - understood. but since in the show electricity already exists there should be a possibility for wifi connection for the reasons Ace stated. Also, technology is advanced enough for most operations to be automated efficiently requiring less maintenance than believed. in the answers to the question about electricity the user states that a relative gets paid a high salary for maintaining wind turbines and then draws the conclusion that that could only mean wind turbines are so inefficient they need constant repair. difference between contengcy checks & actual repair

Comment: Not to get started on the flawed logic that just because so many people work at a plant that means they are spending all their time on the job on actual work. And if planes attract so many zombies because of the noise they should have thought of that as a strategy and that still doesn't answer the private jet question. Most private jets have semi secluded strips and if the noise attracts the zombies they're still too slow to make it. They'd get confused before they could reach the source of the noise.

Comment: Jet fuel is unstable - a few months in a tank and it stops working.  Planes need maintenance, but there hasn't been any for years.  Planes need to land somewhere, and it's a bad idea to take off and just hope that you'll find a landing strip that isn't covered in a refugee-camp-turned-zombie-herd, tons of wreckage, etc.  Also, when the entire planet is overrun by zombies, why bother going from one zombie infested place to another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several studies I've read a while ago indicated that it's the internet network which is most resistant to all kinds of disasters. That is not to say that it will stay up no matter what, just that the losses in the infrastructure will be the least of all communication methods and will be easiest and fastest to have it back up.

*The Last Ship*, for example, featured communications via network of mobile phones with bluetooth (not sure if it wasn't wifi too) to send messages over state lines even. Not much of an example to address your question, but illustrates possibilities.

However, as Gallifreyan says in a comment, there must be someone to maintain the network, and even without that damage would be extensive. I did not watch the series beyond first season (I find all zombie things boring after reading "The Black Tide" series by John Ringo... or stupidly ridiculous like the *iBrain* or something), but I find remarkably low damage level in it. There should be a lot of buildings burned down, for example, burned cars, destroyed infrastructure, including relay stations and exchange cabs etc. And by a lot I mean at least 50%.

And, of course, satellite network is now sufficiently sophisticated to allow for internet connection. I'm surprised no one really uses satellite phones - you can buy an iPhone add-on to convert it to sat phone for less than $200 (i think), and having a smartphone is half-way-there to the IoT.